# How do I copy dropdown lists from Excel to Google Sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, google-spreadsheets

I have an Excel sheet with dropdowns. Each dropdown has anywhere from 40 to 1000 values. Right now, to copy from those values, I need to individually select those values and copy it to a dropdown in Google Sheets. Is there a faster and more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how compatible that feature is, but would it be practical to just open a copy of the workbook in Sheets and delete what you don't need?

Comment: That doesn't help since Google Sheets seems to have problems even processing that many values from the drop down.